# Data is not being retrieved from firebase in recycler view in chat application in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, messenger

[image: Realtime database]

In our authentication  part in firebase  i have stored the mobile  numbers  and correspondig Uid  of the users and in storage part of  firebase i have stored the profile pictures of the users  in the recycler view i need to show the name of user there corresponding  profile picture and there status that they  online or not now kindly help me with retrieving data in my recycler view in my android chat app.

[This screenshot indicate our authentication data stored on firebase. This is my model class:

```
public class firebasemodel {
    String name;
    String image;
    String uid;
    String status;


    public firebasemodel() {
    }

    public firebasemodel(String name, String image, String uid, String status) {
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.uid = uid;
        this.status = status;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

Below is the code where i am retrieving data:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.firestore.FirestoreRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import static androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.VERTICAL;

public class chatFragment extends Fragment {
    //we  are creating customize fragment where first layut is created then class creat to attach then to the activities by creating classes while in simple activities creation both layout and activity is created at same time
    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    ImageView mimageviewofuser;
    FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<firebasemodel, NoteViewHolder> chatAdapter;
    RecyclerView mrecyclerview;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatfragment, container, false);
        firebaseAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        mrecyclerview = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        //fetch all user

        Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("Users");
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<firebasemodel> allusername = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<firebasemodel>().setQuery(query, firebasemodel.class).build();

        chatAdapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<firebasemodel, NoteViewHolder>(allusername) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NoteViewHolder noteViewHolder, int i, @NonNull firebasemodel firebasemodel) {

                noteViewHolder.particularusername.setText(firebasemodel.getName());
                String uri = firebasemodel.getImage();
                Picasso.get().load(uri).into(mimageviewofuser);
                if (firebasemodel.getStatus().equals("Online")) {
                    noteViewHolder.statusofuser.setText(firebasemodel.getStatus());
                    noteViewHolder.statusofuser.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                } else {
                    //onlin/offinle
                    noteViewHolder.statusofuser.setText(firebasemodel.getStatus());
                }
                noteViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }


            @NonNull
            @Override
            public NoteViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chatviewlayout, parent, false);

                return new NoteViewHolder(view);
            }
        };


        mrecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.VERTICAL);
        mrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        //chatAdapter.startListening();
        mrecyclerview.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
        return v;

    }


    public class NoteViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView particularusername;
        private TextView statusofuser;

        public NoteViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            particularusername = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameofuser);
            statusofuser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.statusofuser);
            mimageviewofuser = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageviewofuser);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        chatAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
      
        if(chatAdapter!=null){
            chatAdapter.stopListening();

        }
    }
```

And dependencies i have included are:

```
 implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:20.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.5.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

There is no error in the code but the data is not being retrieved.

The authentication part is working fine but only the issue is to retrieve or to get data from firebase.

The data is not retrieving from the database into the recycler view which we have created.

When we install the app first time it show the recycler view layout in the chat activity only once then after that it disappeared and now it could not showing the users in our chat app.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Have you tried startListening and stopListening in onResume and onPause?

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: Can you show the data in the database that you expect this code to show? Also: I recommend putting a breakpoint in `onBindViewHolder` and running in the debugger to see if it ever gets there.

Comment: @JinalPatel   i have included  start and stop  listening  in my code but its not working

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i have attached the screenshot of my Real Time Database  now. Kindly  have a look on it i will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot you've shown is of the Firebase Realtime Database, but your code is accessing Cloud Firestore. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and the API of one won't be able to access the data of the other.

Instead of `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` you will need to [use `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/database#using-the-firebaserecycleradapter) to read the data from the Realtime Database.